# How to get output from stdout into a string in golang

Tags: go

I have the following code which outputs data from stdout to a file:

```
cmd := exec.Command("ls","lh")
outfile, err := os.Create("./out.txt")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer outfile.Close()

stdoutPipe, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

writer := bufio.NewWriter(outfile)
defer writer.Flush()

err = cmd.Start()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

go io.Copy(writer, stdoutPipe)
cmd.Wait()
```

I need to get the output from stdout into a string value instead of a file. How do I achieve that?

Is there perhaps another function that will allow me to change the io.Copy line to go io.Copy(myStringVariable, stdoutPipe) as I need to read the output of the command and apply some processing to it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could have just assigned the file as the command's Stdout and avoided the pipe and copy goroutine (in which you were losing your read/write errors),

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need the pipe, writer, goroutine, etc. Just use [Cmd.Output](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Output)

```
out, err := exec.Command("ls","lh").Output()
```

You can convert the output `[]byte` to a `string` as needed with `string(out)`

Comment: Short and sweet! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can set the file as the command's `stdout`

```
f, err := os.Create("./out.txt")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer f.Close()

cmd := exec.Command("ls", "-lh")
cmd.Stdout = f
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```