# Running os.execute to get the output

Tags: go, command, command-line-interface

Im using the following code which run command against binary and need to provide output

if I run the command `ftr get apps` in the in my mac I got

`[app1 apps2]`

Now I copy the binary to the test data folder
and run the code below and I want to get the apps, currenlty there is no error but Im not getting also the data, what could be missing here?

```
    Cmd := exec.Command("ftr", "get", "apps")
    Cmd.Dir = "./testdata/"
    err := Cmd.Start()
    fmt.Println(err)
    bytes, e := Cmd.Output()
    fmt.Println(bytes, e)
```

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Run

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get output from stdout into a string in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39478181/how-to-get-output-from-stdout-into-a-string-in-golang)

Answer (score 1):

You won't directly have an output, since the commands takes some time before it writes in stdout/stderr, so you need to basically wait for something to come out.

The way you can do it is by using `bufio.NewScanner`, like this:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    args := "get apps"
    cmd := exec.Command("ftr", strings.Split(args, " ")...)
    cmd.Dir = "./testdata/"

    stdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    cmd.Start()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        m := scanner.Text()
        fmt.Println(m)
    }

    cmd.Wait()
}
```

If your command writes on stderr instead of stdout, you might need to use `cmd.StderrPipe` instead of `cmd.Stdoutpipe` in order to get the output.

Comment: HI, why the wait is after the `for scanner ` ?  the for shouldnt be after the wait ?

Comment: and can I somehow get all the value to 1 string ?

Comment: You can append to a string

Comment: This code should never terminate. scanner.Scan returns true until the reader is closed, but the reader isn't closed until Wait is called.

Answer (score 1):

Calling both Start and Output is redundant.

> Output runs the command and returns its standard output.

Start is used to run the command asynchronously. Simply remove that call:

```
    cmd := exec.Command("ftr", "get", "apps")
    cmd.Dir = "./testdata/"
    b, err := cmd.Output()
    fmt.Println(string(b), err)
```